# Android studio Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

Tags: java, android

[image]

Estaba terminando de programar una conexión a una base de datos remota, pero en cuanto pulso la app, carga unos segundos checando la conexión y se cierra la app, desconozco los motivos, he descargados varias librerías faltan tes y otras versiones de android y aparece el mismo error

Comment: agrega tu código por favor donde realizas la conexión.

Comment: Aparentemente el JSON que estas intentando parsear está mal formado o no tiene una llave a la cual estes haciendo referencia, igual puedes agregar tu código y el JSON que estás parseando.

Comment: el log de error te muestra lo que está causando, cuando le pilles el truqillo ya veras que fácil es solucionar algunos errores.

Comment: El error está en la forma como estas procesando la respuesta. Antes de darle algún formato o hacer algún proceso, fíjate que el resultado sea un `string` para imprimirlo en el `log`.

Answer (score 1):

Este problema

> NullPointerException: lock == null

esta relacionado a que al instanciar un [InputStreamReader()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) usas un valor null de `FileInputStream`:

```
FileInputStream myFileInputStream = null;
InputStreamReader myInputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(myFileInputStream);
```

de hecho me parece que despues tratas de usar JsonParser y por eso obtienes este mensaje:

> Error parsing JsonException: End of input at character 0 of